# Fuelphp architecture

Tags: php, frameworks, module, content-management-system, fuelphp

I want to start working with fuelphp, I have some experience with CI and KOHANA but never used any framework to it's full capacity.

The application I am going to be building will be a inhouse cms system for our clients. It will basically be different type of objects with some meta.

What I really want is to seperate the administration/backoffice from the rest of the application.

As a first option I thought about building it in modules.

As a second option I thought about using FuelPHP´s scaffolding, can anyone tell me what the best solution is?

Should I use the scaffolding & edit it or build the cms in modules?
As I have no experience with fuel at all I hoped some one with experience could point me in de right direction.

Also, what do you guys use as a source of information?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use Laravel ([https://www.laravel.com/](https://www.laravel.com/)) as your Framework of choice?
As their documentation is top notch and I feel it'll suit your purposes much better from your question above.
Regarding resources you can use [https://www.youtube.com/](https://www.youtube.com/) or [https://laracasts.com/](https://laracasts.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This all depends on how you set up the logic and data structure.
The scaffolding is a great tool for flat data, a great starting point.
But if your application relies heavily on related data, abstraction of types/objects, the scaffolding might me more in your way than be a jumpstart.

With my own CMS setup we have a package that holds all the base models (CMS logic). A admin module that provides the admin interface. And a catch-all controller (:any) that handles the CMS page URI's.

So try to look at how complex things need to be and based on that choose what way is right for you. One CMS is definitely not the other.

Also, modules separate larger pieces of functionality. So if you have encapsulated parts of the CMS, having it as a module could be beneficial. But don't go overboard.

Comment: What you describe there seems to be exactly what I am about to build. Thanks for your response, I'll be having lot's of relations. I think i know enough!

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could use [PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com/) which is an awesome Content Management System built on top of CodeIgniter. FuelPHP is a more modern framework which can do some cool stuff, but if you don't want to build a whole CMS then you can't go wrong with Pyro :)

Comment: I acctually do want to build a cms for the learning experience and I want to try something new, I did take PyroCMS in considiration but I really need to learn some new stuff. Thanks though!

Comment: Fair enough. I think every developer see's writing their own CMS as a sort of "right of passage" and every PHP developer I know has tried it at some point. They have now all given up and wished they never bothered. Comically, most of them are using PyroCMS :p

Comment: Hahaha I will keep it in mind, i just want to try some stuff out. If it fails I got this great backup plan of using Pyrocms :)